# How to use keyboard shortcuts of html in JavaScript file in VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I add key shortcuts like just h1 for heading tag (div.container) for division with class name container in **JavaScript file in Virtual Studio Code**
for HTML file they are working but not in javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

by using

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "html"
    },
```

in settings.json